# Node, Mongoose search inside nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following Schema:

```
@Schema()
export class Category extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: 'Category name is required' })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ default: true })
  active: boolean;
}

export const CategorySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Category);
```

And another one that imports this one:

```
@Schema()
export class Skill extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: 'Skill name is required' })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ default: true })
  active: boolean;

  @Prop()
  category: typeof CategorySchema;

}

export const SkillSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Skill);
```

And the following query to find the data:

```
let objects = await this.model
    .find(options)
    .collation({ locale: "pt" })
    .exec();
```

Everything seems to work, but when I call passing the options to search for the nested object id it doesn't find anything:

```
 const options = {
      'category._id': id,
      active: true,
    };
```

When I query other property than the nested id, it seems to work fine:

```
 const options = {
      'category.name': 'test',
      active: true,
    };
```

So, maybe my schema is wrong?
Any clues here?

Comment: Have you ensured that the ID you pass to your options does exist in the DB on the category?

Comment: Yeah, if I do que options query direct on the DB, it works normally

Comment: What happens if you query only by `category._id` is it the same result?

Comment: Yeah, same result "/